# Is there a faster way to iterate through a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am going through a Pandas DataFrame of time slots, trying to compare each time slot to the other slots of the day to find double bookings.

The script takes a while to run. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
for date in df_cal["date"].unique():
    df_date = df_cal[df_cal["date"]==date]
    for current in range(len(df_date)):
        for comp in range(current+1,df_date[df_date["Start"]<df_date.iloc[current]["End"]]["Start"].idxmax()+1):
            df_date.loc[comp,"Double booked"] = True
            df_date.loc[current,"Double booked"] = True
            df_date.loc[comp,"Time_removed"] = max(df_date.loc[comp,"Time_removed"],pd.Timedelta(min(df_date.iloc[current]["End"] - df_date.iloc[comp]["Start"],\
                                                           df_date.iloc[comp]["End"] - df_date.iloc[comp]["Start"])))

    df_temp = pd.concat([df_temp,df_date])
```

Columns are [["MEET_ID","date","Start","End","double_booked","Time_removed"]]

```
[[1943,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 09:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 09:30:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1907,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 10:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 11:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1913,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 11:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1956,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1905,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1914,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1940,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1958,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 14:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 15:30:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1892,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:30:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1929,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 17:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')],
 [1887,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 17:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 18:00:00'),
  False,
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')]]
```

Which should then yield something like this, where double booked meetings are marked as such and the overlapping time is removed from one of the meetings (here it is removed from the second one)
Columns are [["MEET_ID","Start","End","Time_removed","double_booked"]]

```
[[1943,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 09:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 09:30:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1907,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 10:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 11:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1913,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 11:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1956,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1905,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1914,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 12:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00'),
  True],
 [1940,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 13:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  True],
 [1958,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 14:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 15:30:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 01:00:00'),
  True],
 [1892,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:30:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1929,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 16:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 17:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False],
 [1887,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 17:30:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 18:00:00'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'),
  False]]
```

Edit new data 09/07/2018:

```
    Start               End                 Time_removed  Double booked
77  2018-07-02 00:00:00 2018-07-02 10:00:00 00:00:00      True
78  2018-07-02 03:00:00 2018-07-02 08:00:00 05:00:00      True
79  2018-07-02 03:00:00 2018-07-02 08:00:00 05:00:00      True
80  2018-07-02 04:30:00 2018-07-02 09:30:00 03:30:00      True
81  2018-07-02 05:00:00 2018-07-02 10:00:00 04:30:00      True
82  2018-07-02 05:00:00 2018-07-02 10:00:00 05:00:00      True
```

Row 80 should remove 5 hours but only removes 3:30 because it compares to the one row before it. It must have previously computed Time_removed between row 77 and 80 but then it gets replaced by a smaller timediff.

Comment: Use df.iterrows() for iterating the rows in Dataframe.

Comment: can you add data sample?

Comment: Start and End are datetimes, Doubled booked is boolean, Time_removed is a timedelta

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You can also use [numpy's outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) for eliminating the inner double `for` loop.

```
def process_data(df):
    pos = np.argwhere(np.less.outer(df['start'], df['end']))
    indices = df.index[pos]
    unique = indices.ravel().unique()
    date_diff = np.subtract.outer(df['end'], df['start']).max(axis=0)
    return pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.asarray([
            [True]*len(indices),
            np.where(
                np.isin(unique, indices[:, 1]),
                date_diff,
                np.NaN
            )
        ]).T,
        columns=['Double booked', 'Time_removed'],
        index=unique
    )

df_cal.groupby('date').apply(process_data)
```

In any case, this is based on the snippet of the OP only, and without any example data frame and example output (i.e. some kind of unit test), it is hard to say whether it really solves the issue.

Also you have to make sure to not confuse *index* and *position*. In your question you seem to mix `.loc` and `.iloc` as well as usage of `range`. I'm not sure this is giving the result you want.

## Edit

From the data added to OP it looks like the `'Date'` variable is actually dependent on the `'Start'` variable (namely being just the date of the `'Start'` datetime value). Given that this holds we can spare the application of `groupby` and directly apply the outer product in order to get the overlapping items:

```
overlapping = np.less_equal.outer(df['Start'], df['Start']) & np.greater.outer(df['End'], df['Start'])
overlapping &= ~np.identity(len(df), dtype=bool)  # Meetings are overlapping with themselves; need to remove.
overlapping_indices = df.index[np.argwhere(overlapping)].values

df.loc[
    np.unique(overlapping_indices.ravel()),
    'double_booked'
] = True

df.loc[
    overlapping_indices[:, 1],
    'Time_removed'
] = (
    np.minimum(df.loc[overlapping_indices[:, 0], 'End'], df.loc[overlapping_indices[:, 1], 'End'])
    - np.maximum(df.loc[overlapping_indices[:, 0], 'Start'], df.loc[overlapping_indices[:, 1], 'Start'])
).values
```

However from the example data it is not clear how you want to deal with marking overlapping meetings as double booked. For the `12:30:00 - 13:00:00` meetings you marked only the second one, while for the `13:00:00 - 16:00:00` and `14:30:00 - 15:30:00` you marked both as double booked.

## Edit 2

In order to consider multiple (> 3) overlapping meetings we need to compute the overlap times for all pairs of meetings and then consider the maximum overlap for those that actually have a (positive) overlap. The following solution requires the data to be sorted by start time:

```
# This requires the data frame to be sorted by `Start` time.

start_times = np.tile(df['Start'].values, (len(df), 1))
end_times = np.tile(df['End'].values, (len(df), 1))
overlap_times = np.triu(np.minimum(end_times, end_times.T) - np.maximum(start_times, start_times.T))
overlap_times[np.diag_indices(len(overlap_times))] = np.timedelta64(0)
overlap_indices = df.index[np.argwhere(overlap_times > np.timedelta64(0))]
overlaps_others_indices = np.unique(overlap_indices[:, 1])

df.loc[
    np.unique(overlap_indices.ravel()),
    'double_booked'
] = True

df.loc[
    overlaps_others_indices,
    'Time_removed'
] = pd.Series(overlap_times.max(axis=0), index=df.index)[overlaps_others_indices]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think groupby is the right way to go, however, it still doesn't quite work.

I have added some input and output data above to show how it works.

Comment: thank you so much!

I wanted to mark both meetings as double booked, but only remove time from the one that starts latest. This is a problem when they are both 12:30 - 13:00 because it removes 0:30 from both, but I fixed it as shown here:
`df_cal.loc[
            np.maximum(overlapping_indices[:,0],overlapping_indices[:, 1]),
            'Time_removed'
        ] = (`

Again, thank you so much for the help. Do you have any online resources you can recommend to help me improve?

Comment: @GustavFjorder By using `loc` (with index) for accessing the *later* meeting you require the meetings to be ordered in the database. A safer way of doing it is to only consider the upper triangle of the `overlapping` matrix (later meetings are stored as the columns). So before extracting the indices you can do `overlapping = np.triu(overlapping)` which will set the lower triangle to zero (only considering the later meeting). As for the resources I'd recommend getting familiar with numpy in general as it allows for great performance improvements (just search for numpy tutorials online).

Comment: Awesome :) I just noticed that the time_removed is too small when we have triple bookings. I have updated the data above with an example where all meetings are between 00:00 - 10:00 so only the first meeting should get any time, all the rest should be removed, but this isn't the case.

Comment: @GustavFjorder See my updated answer. This now requires the data frame to be sorted by `Start` time however (so that the upper triangle of overlaps really represents "later" meetings). Maybe it can also be done without presorting but it's better to ask a separate question for this.